# How can I fix a "could not deduce" error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to get Pandoc to process my citations while rendering a file. Currently I'm using [this function in my fork of Rib](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/jonreeve.com/blob/master/src/Pandoc.hs#L67), which looks like this:

```hs
-- | Render a Pandoc document to HTML
render :: Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
render doc =
  either error id $ first show $ runExcept $ do
    runPure'
    $ fmap toHtmlRaw
    $ writeHtml5String writerSettings doc
```

Since `processCitations` has the type signature `PandocMonad m => Pandoc -> m Pandoc` I figure I have to run the action? So I've tried this:

```hs
-- | Render a Pandoc document to HTML
render :: Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
render doc = do 
  processed <- processCitations doc
  either error id $ first show $ runExcept $ do
    runPure'
    $ fmap toHtmlRaw
    $ writeHtml5String writerSettings processed
```

But I get an error I'm not used to seeing:

```
    • Could not deduce (PandocMonad m)
        arising from a use of ‘processCitations’
      from the context: Monad m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   render :: forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
        at src/Pandoc.hs:70:1-41
      Possible fix:
        add (PandocMonad m) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            render :: forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
```

I'm not sure I understand what this means. I've tried adding `PandocMonad Identity` to the context for that function, but that apparently means I have to add it to the context of every other function in this chain, too. That can't be right, can it? How can I just run `processCitations` without having to rewrite my whole system from the ground up?

**Edit**: Based on the comment below, I also tried this:

```hs
-- | Render a Pandoc document to HTML
render :: Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
render doc =
  either error id $ first show $ runExcept $ do
    let processed = processCitations doc :: Pandoc
    runPure' $ fmap toHtmlRaw $ writeHtml5String writerSettings processed
```

But this is telling me that it can't match the type "Pandoc." Probably because `processCitations` returns a `m Pandoc`. Similarly with this case:

```hs
-- | Render a Pandoc document to HTML
render :: Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
render doc =
  either error id $ first show $ runExcept $ do
    processed <- processCitations doc :: Pandoc
    runPure' $ fmap toHtmlRaw $ writeHtml5String writerSettings processed
```

I tried to Hoogle for a function with the type `m Pandoc -> Pandoc`, but no luck.

Comment: Presumably `processCitations` should be moved into the existing `do` block rather than introducing a new `do` block. But I'm no pandoc expert, so I'm only about 70% confident.

Comment: I've just edited by question to reflect that idea. It doesn't get me much closer to a solution. I still have this issue of a mismatch between `Pandoc` and `m Pandoc`.

Comment: Well it certainly can't have type `Pandoc`. Why do you hate letting it have type `m Pandoc`? What goes wrong if you just delete the type annotation on `processCitations`?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is process the citations on my Pandoc doc before giving it to `writeHtml5String`. `writeHtml5String` takes a `Pandoc` and settings and returns `m Text`. If I give it `m Pandoc` instead of `Pandoc`, it raises an error: `couldn't match expected type Pandoc`.

Comment: What goes wrong if you take your last code snippet and *just* delete the type annotation on `processCitations`?

Comment: It's the same `could not deduce` error as above.

Comment: `processCitations` inherently involves state, and potential errors. You can't implicitly escape such effects in Haskell. You can either do what the error says and add `PandocMonad m` to the context where needed. Otherwise, specialize the `m` to `PandocPure` in only the `processCitations` call site and unwrap the monad transformers

Comment: For sure, but isn't there a way to handle those errors, in one function, such that you don't need to handle them in all functions across your codebase? How do I unwrap the monad transformers?

Comment: @Jonathan "`processCitations` inherently involves *state* **and** potential errors." You're ignoring one half of what Chase said. It's expecting to be called in the thread of a `PandocMonad` monadic process, so that it can interact with the state used by that process. It's extremely unlikely that there's any way for you to call it outside of that environment and have it work properly, even if you can manage to handle the errors and invent fake state such that you can appease the typechecker.

Comment: I'm at a total loss about how to proceed here. I can't even get it to work *with* 20+ code changes. I've started a new question with a minimal example, hoping that I can get that to work, and then build it out from there. Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71358509/how-can-i-process-citations-using-pandocs-citeproc-in-haskell

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first step I reproduced a minimal but *complete* version of your code (complete means: I can compile it and actually get the error you're reporting, not just all the missing imports and other definitions). In future, you are *much* more likely to get a response if you do that and put it in the question. I did not need all 156 lines of the file you linked, but I did need more than you actually gave us in the question. If you hadn't happened to catch me in a moment when I could be bothered doing that, I would have moved on without looking into this question further.

Here it is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Except

import Data.Bifunctor

import Lucid

import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Citeproc

-- | Render a Pandoc document to HTML
render :: Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
render doc = do
  processed <- processCitations doc
  either error id $ first show $ runExcept $ do
    runPure'
    $ fmap toHtmlRaw
    $ writeHtml5String writerSettings processed


runPure' :: MonadError PandocError m => PandocPure a -> m a
runPure' = liftEither . runPure

writerSettings :: WriterOptions
writerSettings = def {writerExtensions = pandocExtensions}
```

Now, you were entirely correct here:

> Since `processCitations` has the type signature `PandocMonad m => Pandoc -> m Pandoc` I figure I have to run the action?

And you wrote the correct code in the implementation, as far as I can see. However you *do* have to update the type signature of your function. `processCitations` has a requirement that `PandocMonad m` holds; you are calling it in a context that only provides `Monad m`.

That is the type error, and there is nothing you can do to make it go away without changing the signature. Looking at what [the docs say about `PandocMonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.17.1.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class.html#t:PandocMonad), I hope you can see that a `PandocMonad` constraint requires `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, and `MonadError PandocError` instances as well, as well as 19 methods of its own. If you keep the type for your function as `render :: Monad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()`, you are claiming that you can call `processCitations`, which needs all of that, and that you are able to it with *any monad whatsoever*. You said `render` could work for any monad, even `Identity`, which doesn't actually provide any functionality at all over the base type! That is a promise you obviously are not going to be able to keep. You need to change the promise (AKA the type signature), not look for magic functions that will fulfil your promise for you.

If you change the type signature to this, then the code simply compiles:

```
render :: PandocMonad m => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()
```

That's what "add `(PandocMonad m)` to the context of the type signature for: `render`" means, nothing to do with `PandocMonad Identity`. (Well, actually adding it to the context literally would mean `(Monad m, PandocMonad m)`, but `PandocMonad m` already implies `Monad m` so we can simplify).

It's also the type that GHC infers for `render` if you remove the type signature and change nothing else; it does not produce the same error. Probably you were getting the same error at a different function that calls `render`.

I'm afraid you **will** need to change the type signature of any function that was calling `render` and only providing `Monad m`, by the same reasoning as above. This will be very quick however (hardly "rewriting your whole system from the ground up"), as the compiler will point you to exactly the functions that need to change since it will detect the missing constraint, exactly as you've seen here. Those functions that were just passing on a `Monad m` constraint from their type, will be also just need the addition of the 6 letters `Pandoc` in their type; those functions that were actually *satisfying* the `Monad` constraint (often there will only be one of these) will now need to satisfy the `PandocMonad` constraint instead - which they might already be doing if they pick a `Monad` that is already a `PandocMonad`.

The only alternatives are for `render` to concretely use some particular `PandocMonad` (like `PandocIO` or `PandocPure`) rather than use polymorphism to support any `PandocMonad`, or to concretely use a monad you can turn into a concrete member of `PandocMonad` (e.g. `PandocIO a` is a newtype wrapper for `ExceptT PandocError (StateT CommonState IO) a`, so theoretically you can take that and turn it into `PandocIO a` just to run `processCitations`). Those will be worse options, and still won't get you out of updating `render`'s callers, so I would not even consider them.

It is a reality of strongly typed programming that when you change something deeper in the call stack so that it requires more of its environment (adding arguments or constraints, fixing types that used to be universal, etc), you will often need to also change the callers. This happens in other languages too (e.g. in Java if you switch a method to requiring a more specific subclass than it used to, you'll have to update all the callers that were accepting a more generic class and passing it down). Even in dynamic languages like Python you when you make an analogous change you might not need to update any type signatures, but you *will* usually need to use your comprehensive test suite and/or painful hours of debugging to find all the places where the old code needs to be updated to meet the new requirements.

Comment: If I add `PandocMonad Identity =>` here, and then add it to about 20 other functions all up the chain, that almost works, until I get to `main`, where changing the context on main to `main :: PandocMonad Identity => IO ()` says "No instance for (PandocMonad Identity)." It really seems a bit much to change the type signatures on 20 functions, in two different modules across my codebase, just to be able to process citations in one place. Why is it that I didn't require `Monad m` to be in the context of absolutely everything? I feel like Pandoc just needs error handling, and that'll fulfill

Comment: its requirements, no? It doesn't need me to do it everywhere? It's not that I *just* have to change `Monad m` to `PandocMonad Identity`, but everywhere else, too. For example, `renderPage` has the type signature `Route a -> a -> Html ()`. But I have to change that to `renderPage :: PandocMonad Identity => Route a -> a -> Html ()`. [Here are all the changes that I have to make](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/jonreeve.com/commit/1df9185e0020aa8f847d4c11f8f8781ee56324e6), and that's not even all of them, since my compiler tells me I need to handle `main`.

Comment: @Jonathan Hangon, there's a separate issue there. Both I (and the original suggestion from the compiler) said to use `PandocMonad m`, not `PandocMonad Identity`. I can see from your diff you had places where you *don't* have a `Monad m` constraint, and I presume that's what made you decide to add `PandocMonad Identity`. However a constraint with no variables is never going to help you; either the compiler can see an instance for that type, in which case you don't need the constraint, or the compiler can't, in which case adding the constraint doesn't fix the real problem.

Comment: @Jonathan (1/2) I suggest you revert that diff, change the type signature on render to exactly `render :: (PandocMonad m) => Pandoc -> HtmlT m ()`. Then similarly fix all the places where the compiler says "Could not deduce (PandocMonad m) ... from the context: Monad m", but **not** where it says "No instance PandocMonad Identity". Those are the places that I mentioned in my answer where a particular monad was chosen; before your code was choosing `Identity`, but that *doesn't* have a `PandocMonad`.

Comment: @Jonathan (2/2) In those places you need to change the *code*, not just the type, so that it uses a `PandocMonad`. if you don't know how to do that, you can get help by asking a separate question here (please reduce to a small but complete compilable example). If external code (like in Rib? I don't know it) is instantiating the monad in use, you may be out of luck, unfortunately.

Comment: I've started a new question with a minimal example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71358509/how-can-i-process-citations-using-pandocs-citeproc-in-haskell