# How can I process citations using Pandoc's Citeproc, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pandoc, citations

Starting with ["A Simple Example" from the Pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/using-the-pandoc-api.html#a-simple-example), I want to add citation processing functionality. [The docs for Text.Pandoc.Citeproc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.17.1.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Citeproc.html) show a function `processCitations` which supposedly processes citations. Yet given simple org-mode input, and a citation `[@test2022]`, it doesn't seem to work. It compiles and runs just fine, but the output of the code below is: `<p><span class="spurious-link" target="url"><em>testing</em></span> [@test2022]</p>`, i.e., the citation isn't actually processed. What am I doing wrong? And how can I get this to process my citation?

```hs
import Text.Pandoc
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Text.Pandoc.Filter
import Text.Pandoc.Citeproc

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runIO $ do
    doc <- readOrg def (T.pack "#+bibliography: test.bib\n [[url][testing]]\n[@test2022]")
    processed <- processCitations doc
    writeHtml5String def processed
  html <- handleError result
  TIO.putStrLn html
```

For reference, here's my `test.bib` bibtex file:

```
@Book{test2022,
  author =    {Barus, Foobius},
  title =        {The Very Persistent Foo or Bar},
  publisher =    {Foobar Publications, Inc},
  year =         {2022}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself, eventually. Turns out you have to set some extensions, and some options, and set the metadata for the document:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.Pandoc
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Text.Pandoc.Filter
import Text.Pandoc.Citeproc
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Text.Pandoc.Builder (setMeta)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let exts = extensionsFromList [ Ext_citations ]
  let readerOptions = def{ readerExtensions = exts}
  let writerOptions = def{ writerExtensions = exts}
  result <- runIO $ do
    doc <- readMarkdown readerOptions (T.pack "Testing testing\n[@test2022]\n")
    let doc' = setMeta (T.pack "bibliography") (T.pack "test.bib") doc :: Pandoc
    processed <- processCitations doc'
    writeHtml5String writerOptions processed
  html <- handleError result
  TIO.putStrLn html
```

Comment: I saw your post and it made me realize that we should be parsing the `#+bibliography: test.bib` line as metadata -- just pushed a change to the org reader that does this.